# Вызов метода одного класса из другого

Tags: php

Есть класс для работы с *IMAP* протоколом.   Назовем его `class1`

А так же есть класс для работы с сокетами. Назовем его `class2`

Я хочу из `class1` дергать методы `class2`.

Нужно все два метода - `socketRequest($socketRequest)` и `socketResponse()`.

Т.е отправить запрос и принять ответ.

Как реализовать подобное?

**Идея 1:** передать в конструктор `class1` объект `class2` и потом уже вызывать нужные методы. Но тогда получается, что классы жестко связаны.

**Идея 2:** В `class2` реализовать `__invoke($socketRequest)`. Далее как так же передаю объект `class2` в `class1`, но в отличие от первой идеи, я не вызываю конкретные методы а сам объект использую как функцию - `class2($imapRequest)`.
Т.е привязки сильной нету, можно потом будет подсунуть все что хочешь.

Какие идеи?

Comment: вы придумали интерфейсы, только здесь они не нужны и первый вариант вполне окрректный.

Comment: Не вдаваясь в терминалогию, чем для вас плохая идея 1? Все плохо было бы, если б в class1 без заморочек было написано new class2 и дальше тестируй/подменяй это как хочешь... А так все вполне прилично и тестируемо.

Comment: 1 - Вот честно говоря когда прочитал первый комментарий про интерфейс, то первый вариант показался не таким уж и плохим.
Я про него просто не подумал..
Т.е я пишу интерфейс и реализую его в классе. Получается заранее указываю какие методы должны присутствовать в классе для возможности работы с class1. А далее если хочу что-то поменять, например другой класс для работы с сокетами написать, то реализуя интерфейс я сразу делаю его пригодным для работы с class1.
Правильно я понимаю?

2 - а вторая идея совсем изврат?

Comment: да. да, вторая идея - хуже некуда, с классом NuclearBomb тоже весьма успешно заработает.

Comment: Все понял. Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: _что классы жестко связаны_ это в пхп то? только если явно укажете тип, все таки duck typing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вашу задачу можно решить с помощью одного из следующих типов отношений - *агрегация*, либо *композиция*.

**Агрегация** – применяется когда один класс должен быть контейнером других классов. Причем время существования содержащихся классов никак не зависит от времени существования класса контейнера.

**пример:**

```
class class2 
{
    public function socketRequest($socketRequest)
    {
        //
    }
    public function socketResponse()
    {
        //
    }
}

class class1 
{
    private $foo;

    public function __constructor(class2 $Foo)
    {
        $this->foo = $Foo;
    }

    public function socketRequest($socketRequest)
    {
        return $this->foo->socketRequest($socketRequest);
    }
    public function socketResponse()
    {
        return $this->foo->socketResponse();
    }
}
```

Если в ходе выполнения программы объект `class1` будет уничтожен, это никак не повлияет на объект класса `class2`.

**Композиция** более строгий вариант отношений. В отличии от агрегации, композиция имеет жёсткую зависимость времени существования экземпляров класса контейнера и экземпляров содержащихся классов.

**пример:**

```
class class2 
{
    public function socketRequest($socketRequest)
    {
        //
    }
    public function socketResponse()
    {
        //
    }
}

class class1 
{
    private $foo;

    public function __constructor()
    {
        $this->foo = new class2;
    }

    public function socketRequest($socketRequest)
    {
        return $this->foo->socketRequest($socketRequest);
    }
    public function socketResponse()
    {
        return $this->foo->socketResponse();
    }
}
```

Если в ходе выполнения программы объект `class1` будет уничтожен, это повлечет за собой уничтожение объекта класса `class2`

Чтобы определить какой тип отношений Вам подходит нужно ответить на вопрос должен ли класс `class2` существовать вне класа `class1`. Если `class2` планируется использовать где то еще - используйте агрегацию, если нет - композицию.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Сейчас вот на википедии читал про паттерн стратегия. Первый вариант напоминает его

Comment: ну у Вас вроде не сильно сложная задача чтобы в патерны уходить но для общего развития рекомендую о зависимостях класов почитать это http://habrahabr.ru/post/244517/