# Mysql запросы внутри функций и классов/область видимости

Tags: mysql, функции

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как использовать mysql запросы внутри функций и классов?

Единственный вариант решения задачи, который мне известен - во всех функциях и классах объявлять переменную как `global`, но что-то мне подсказывает, что это неверное решение задачи.

Использую PDO. Как сейчас делаю запросы к mysql внутри всех своих функций, пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я уже задавал похожий [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481387/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE) .

Answer (score 1):

Использовал этот singleton для решения задачи:
github.com/laxxen/Database

Как альтернатива - можно использовать этот:
github.com/Sicaa/starter-kit-sql

Сценарий для таких же глупых дураков, как я:

Вставили в свой index.php:

```
include 'database.php'; //(не забыв в нем поменять данные для подключения к БД)
```

Далее в классах и функциях, везде, где вам нужно, используем, например, так:

```
 $db = Database::getInstance();
 $results = $db->Query("SELECT ......... LIMIT 1");
 $a = $results->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $a = $results->fetchAll();
```

Но пока я разбирался с синглтонами и global переменными, я пришел к выводу, что оба варианта неверны. Я переделал архитектуру своего приложения и теперь мне не нужны global переменные и синглтоны для решения задач.

Вывод: если вам вдруг нужна global переменная или синглтон, значит вы где-то допустили ошибку в проектировании. Измените подход. Если этого сделать нельзя, что ж, тогда деваться некуда.